# How to connect 2 servers to each other as double vpn?

Tags: server, network-manager, vpn, proxy

I have configured an L2TP/IPsec vpn server (A) on Ubuntu, and i want to connect this vpn server to another one (serverB). Because I live in Iran and the internet is heavily censored by the government. They shut down the internet and just run on the intranet. I have found some servers which is always connected to Internet and will never down, but even the traffic of them is passed through Iran Filtering System. So, I have transformed one of those to a Virtual Private Server(L2TP/IPsec) and now I want to connect it to another vpn in order to bypass the Filtering.

I want to first connect my computer to "VPN Server A"(configured by you and it's inside Iran's firewall) and then connect this VPN (Server A) to VPN Server B(which is outside Iran's firewall)?

**Tor didn't work in iran

Answer (score 0):

Basically, ipsec is good, but l2tp and ike will be detected by their ports, so maybe their ports are blocked.
You can choose socks proxy with v2ray. Socks has an option to also pass your dns traffic inside the proxy and has good applications for both android and ios, but it's detectable also.
If you want to hidden your server, you can run a fake website on it, and also fake upload traffic, also if you use tls for this proxy, you can use SNI to pretending that you are browsing other websites.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).